# Calling random in secrets module

Tags: python, c, class, random, cpython

I am trying to understand how the [secrets module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/secrets.py) of Python works and which modules it calls when generating random numbers. I don’t have a lot of programming experience, so please stay with me.

In the `secrets` module, they call a specific class of the `Random` module called `Systemrandom`. The class `Systemrandom` is then named `_sysrand` and the function `_randbelow` of this class is called. Here is the relevant code from `secrets`:

```
from random import SystemRandom

_sysrand = SystemRandom()

randbits = _sysrand.getrandbits
choice = _sysrand.choice

def randbelow(exclusive_upper_bound):
    """Return a random int in the range [0, n)."""
    if exclusive_upper_bound <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Upper bound must be positive.")
    return _sysrand._randbelow(exclusive_upper_bound)
```

However, when I check the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/random.py) of random.py, I see that it actually defines two classes: `Random` and `Systemrandom`.
I only see the `randbelow` function defined in the `Random` class (in lines 231-271). It does not appear in the `Systemrandom` class.
The relevant code in random.py is:

```
class Random(_random.Random):
...
    [Define _randbelow] 
...
class SystemRandom(Random):
...
```

So suppose that you call the `randbelow` function from the `secrets` module. Then the computer will search the `random` module in the `SystemRandom` class. But there it will not find the `_randbelow` function. What am I missing?

Comment: `class SystemRandom(Random):` - it's inherited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that there are two classes defined:

```
class Random(_random.Random):
```

and

```
class SystemRandom(Random):
```

`SystemRandom` is a subclass which inherits from `Random`.

`_randbelow` is defined in the `Random` class.

This means `_randbelow` can also be used in the subclass `SystemRandom`.

We say that `_randbelow` is inherited from `Random`.